# Fourier inversion for $L^1$ holds at the Lebesgue set.

Tags: reference-request, fourier-transform

I am looking for a reference for the following result:

> Let $f \in L^1(\Bbb R)$ be such that $\hat{f} \in L^1$. Then, $$f(x) = \int_{\Bbb R}\hat{f}(\lambda)e^{2\pi i\lambda x}\,{\mathrm d}\lambda$$
> holds for all $x \in L_f$, where $L_f$ is the Lebesgue set of $f$ defined as $$\left\{x \in \Bbb R : \lim_{r \to 0}\frac{1}{r^2}\int_{B(x, r)}|f(y) - f(x)|\,{\mathrm d}x = 0\right\}.$$

In other words, I wish to show that the Fourier inversion formula holds for $x$ in the Lebesgue set of $f$. ($\hat f$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$.)

Comment: See the last part of the approved answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3569803/on-the-proof-of-the-fourier-inversion-theorem-using-continuous-fej%c3%a9r-kernels?rq=1

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Thank you, I'll try to work out the details.